# Converting string to array when using tag xmlns:soapenv

Tags: php, soap

I have the follwing string:

```
$string='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:bac="http://backupbank.com/">      <soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>
           <bac:CreateUser>
            <bac:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bac:username>anandneema</bac:username>
            <bac:product>Workstation</bac:product>
            <bac:credentials>
               <bac:server>serveripaddress</bac:server>
               <bac:user>username</bac:user>
               <bac:password>password</bac:password>
            </bac:credentials>
         </bac:request>
      </bac:CreateUser>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>';

$xmldata=simplexml_load_string($string);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($xmldata);
```

It is not parsing the data.

But when I use:

```
 $string='<soapenv:Envelope>    <soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>
      <bac:CreateUser>
         <bac:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bac:username>anandneema</bac:username>
            <bac:product>Workstation</bac:product>
            <bac:credentials>
               <bac:server>serveripaddress</bac:server>
               <bac:user>username</bac:user>
               <bac:password>password</bac:password>
            </bac:credentials>
         </bac:request>
      </bac:CreateUser>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>';

$xmldata=simplexml_load_string($string); echo "<pre>"; print_r($xmldata);
```

Actually when I am removing the attributes: `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`
`xmlns:bac="http://backupbank.com/"`

Then it parses the data

Can any one suggest to me what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have much idea on this but try calling the service by properly format the xml as string then use CURL may be something like in this quesion

[Handling web service errors within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172109/handling-web-service-errors-within-php)